# How to plot prediction map in SVC algorithm

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Currently I am testing an SVC model, and I'd like to create decision maps like those shown in books or in link https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html:

**Example of what I have in mind:**
[image: Example of what I have in mind]

But I have no idea, how it's done or if theres a function for this.
I've tried looking on google but found nothing.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.DecisionBoundaryDisplay.html#sklearn.inspection.DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator and also https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.DecisionBoundaryDisplay.html#sklearn.inspection.DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator

Answer (score 0):

use matplotlib. test make_blobs data and try to add more style

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=40, centers=2, random_state=42, cluster_std=1.25)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=100, cmap="bwr");
plt.title('SVM Linear Kernel')
plt.ylabel('Sepal Width (cm)')
plt.xlabel('Sepal length (cm)')
plt.show()
```

you will a plot like this:
[image]